# curlでページを読み込みソースを表示する。

Tags: c

質問しますよろしくお願いします。
C言語でCURLを使用しウェブページを読み込み出力したいのですが、上手く行かず困っています。

以下コードになります。

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "curl/curl.h"

struct Buffer{
    char *data;
    int data_size;
};
size_t buffer_writer(char *ptr,size_t size,size_t nmemb,void *stream){
    struct Buffer *buf = (struct Buffer *)stream;
    char block = size * nmemb;  
    if(!buf)return block ;
    if (!buf->data) {
        buf->data = (char *)malloc(block);
    }else{
        buf->data = (char *)realloc(buf->data,buf->data_size + size);
    }
    if(buf->data){
        memcpy(buf->data,ptr,block);
        buf->data_size += block;
    }
    printf("end");
    return block;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {   
    struct Buffer *buf;
    buf = (struct Buffer*)malloc(sizeof(struct Buffer));
    buf->data = NULL;
    buf->data_size = 0;
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.yahoo.co.jp/");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,buf);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,buffer_writer);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    printf("%d",buf->data_size);
    free(buf->data);
    free(buf);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

おかしなところがあれば、ご指摘をいただきたいです。
この状態の結果は『0』です。

Comment: 1) `char block = size * nmemb;` --> `size_t block = size * nmemb; `

Comment: 2) `buf->data = (char *)realloc(buf->data,buf->data_size + size);` --> `buf->data = (char *)realloc(buf->data,buf->data_size + block);`

Comment: 3) `memcpy(buf->data,ptr,block);` --> `memcpy(buf->data + buf->data_size, ptr, block);`

Comment: [curl libを使ってみる](http://qiita.com/edo_m18/items/a0073d81431bfd5681e2) の「データを保持する」に記載されているコードを参考にしたのでしょうか。

Comment: はい、がっつり参考にしました・・・

Answer (score 2):

curl_easy_setopt()は処理のセットアップであり、まだ何も行っていません。
実際の実行はcurl_easy_perform(curl)を呼んでください。

Comment: あ、忘れてました・・・ありがとうございます。

Comment: curl_easy_perform(curl)をつけますと、EXEC_BAD_ACCESSになり終了してしまいます。これは、アクセスしようとしたが解放済みで参照不可という解釈で正しいですか？？もしそうだとした場合、回避策はどのような処理を辿ると上手く行きますか？？

Comment: (全コードトレースしていないので簡単なコメントですが)BLUEPIXYさんが記載していただいているbuf周りの修正は行われましたでしょうか？

Comment: はい、ご指摘いただいた箇所は修正しました。

Comment: 解決しました。お恥ずかしいことながらURLが間違ってました・・・